# Unix Command readlink, xargs,sed,cut

Tags: shell, unix, command-line, cut, xargs

I read this command somewhere.. dont have any idea what is it.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -follow | cut -d/ -f2 | xargs -I % readlink -f  % | cut -d\/ -f7,14 | sed 's/\// /g' | sort
```

I searched for it, and got what maxdepth and type mean, but not about `-follow`, `cut -f -f2`, `readlink` and `sed`.

What does `-f7,14` mean?

Comment: `man cut` will show you. Good luck.

Comment: BUt what does xargs -I % readlink -f %  mean?

Comment: sed 's/// /g' is incorrect command maybe it should look like 's/\// /g'

Comment: oh.. yeah , sorry its, find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -follow | cut -d/ -f2 | xargs -I % readlink -f  % | cut -d\/ -f7,14 | sed 's/\// /g' | sort

Comment: Searching did not produce man pages? [find](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) [xargs](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs) [cut](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cut) [readlink](http://linux.die.net/man/1/readlink) [sed](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sed)

Answer (score 1):

Break it down is the best approach.

First a find command is run in current directory . , limit the search to depth to just to current directory by using the value 1 and search type limited to just files (type f) and to use actual file properties in case it gets a symbolic link by using -follow. i.e. follow a symbolic link.

i.e till here

find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -follow

from there simple cut - cut the second field(-f2) if the delimiter is / (-d/) to get rid of dot  - the current directory that you would see from find's listing.

that's till here
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -follow | cut -d/ -f2

then pipe the output to xargs and run a command readlink which prints the actual file linked to a symbolic link  in canonicalize mode(to give name of the chain linked file) [Check example here](http://linuxers.org/howto/how-use-readlink-command-find-canonical-filename-symbolic-link)

Then the output is passed to cut to get 7th and 14th fields if the delimiter is "\".

You would see any output from here on only if you have link with that depth, but it's possible.

And then with sed 's/// /g' the output is searched for "\" (escaping is done by /)and is replaced by " " whitespace. sed's global search and replace mode - to replace all occurrence of \ with " " whitespace.

What is intention with the command ? I think it looks for symbolic links and then find actual linked file. I don't quite understand the reason of cutting just 7th and 14th field and then replacing slash with. Probably user was looking for special depth of directories.